# Proving function is differentiable

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

Suppose we have $f : \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is differentiable. Now we fix some unit vector $u \in \mathbb{R}^{m},$ with fixed $p, q \in \mathbb{R}.$ Is the function
$$ g(t) = \langle u, f(p + t(q - p)) \rangle $$
differentiable?

Comment: It is a composition of differentiable functions: $t\mapsto p+t(q-p)$, which is linear, $f$ and $v\mapsto \langle u,v\rangle$, which is linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is differentiable implies that each of its component function is differentiable on reals. Hence,
$$g(t)=\sum_{i=1}^mu_if_i(p+t(q-p))$$
is differentiable, because it is sum of compositions of differentiable and linear functions.